# sending data to server using kivy

Tags: android, python, kivy

I am creating a app using kivy. I have installed simple dhcp server on my android.

```
import urllib
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest

def bug_posted(req, result):
    print('Our bug is posted !')
    print(result)

params = urllib.urlencode({'@number': 12524, '@type': 'issue',
'@action': 'show'})
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Accept': 'text/plain'}
req = UrlRequest('<ip>:<port>', on_success=bug_posted, req_body=params,
    req_headers=headers)
print req

result = "test"
bug_posted(req, result)
```

But, when I run this code, it wont logged in my server. how can I log into my server?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need a dhcp server on android, is this code running on android or on another machine? Also, urlrequest probably doesn't work if you don't run the kivy loop in the mean time.

Comment: my main goal is, I have an test file named test.txt in which I have some content in it. contents of test.txt are incrementing every moment. I want to upload that content to my server so that I can see from server. I am doing this because there is no way that I can send file to some email id without reflecting to users sent items in mails.

Answer (score 2):

Did you give the ”INTERNET” permission to your app? Did you check in the logs (a that the service was running? did you try with something else that the thread-based urlrequest (that is useful in gui to avoid blocking, but less in a service)?

(I still don't understand why you mention the dhcp server, your device still access the internet correctly, right?)

Comment: yes but the main problem is, I need the log file need to reach back to me. there are 2 options. 1. via mail, but in this users sent mailbox will be populated and user will always known abt it. 2. to send the content of file on stream to any server. can you guide me how can i achieve?

Comment: You didn't answer any of my questions. I'm not sure how i can help you without any useful info. kivy is python, you can use the usual network libraries in the service, urlrequest is just there to avoid blocking the UI if you do network on the app size, it's not needed in a service. Also, sending the android log to your server without the user knowing about it seems a little nasty, and i think you need specific permissions to read that log in recent versions of android, please make clear to the user that you do that, whatever the way you do it (and please answer all my questions!)

Comment: yes i gave permissions now but i do not understand how can i retrieve that log in clients android to me? I dont know ways by which i can do that. can you please guide?

Comment: did you look at urlrequest? (kivy.network.urlrequest) it makes it easy to do http requests in kivy, you can pass data in the body, and get them on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling:

```
req.wait()
```

near the end of your code

```
import urllib
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest

def bug_posted(req, result):
    print('Our bug is posted !')
    print(result)

params = urllib.urlencode({'@number': 12524, '@type': 'issue',
'@action': 'show'})
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Accept': 'text/plain'}
req = UrlRequest('<ip>:<port>', on_success=bug_posted, req_body=params,
    req_headers=headers)
req.wait()
```

without it the request does not seem to fire for me.